# Assigning data to properties using a large switch statement... is there a more dynamic way to do this?

Tags: c#, reflection, refactoring

So I'm pulling some information out of a database and I need to map it to my model's properties. My first attempt at this yielded a large switch statement which is following an obvious pattern. I am wondering if this fragile code can be expressed in a more dynamic fashion.

```
foreach (AttributeValue attributeValue in attributeValues)
{
    string label = attributes.First(a => a.ID == attributeValue.AttributeID).Name;
    switch (attributeValue.AttributeName)
    {
        case "TaskSequence":
            TaskSequenceLabel = label;
            break;
        case "TaskStatus":
            TaskStatusLabel = label;
            break;
        case "InstallChangeNumber":
            InstallChangeNumberLabel = label;
            break;
        case "InstallChangeStart":
            InstallChangeStartLabel = label;
            break;
        case "InstallChangeEnd":
            InstallChangeEndLabel = label;
            break;
        case "SubmittedDateTime":
            SubmittedDateTimeLabel = label;
            break;
        case "InstalledDateTime":
            InstalledDateTimeLabel = label;
            break;
    }
}
```

Basically what I am thinking is "Map labels to properties which have the label's value + "Label""

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using something like `NHibernate` or `Entity Framework`?

Comment: We partially use NHibernate. It is used for new code, but I still have to work with technical debt in some areas of our project, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with reflection:

```
foreach (AttributeValue attributeValue in attributeValues)
{
    string label = attributes.First(a => a.ID == attributeValue.AttributeID).Name;
    string propertyName = attributeValue.AttributeName + "Label";
    PropertyInfo pi = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    // check for null, if it is possible that property not exists
    pi.SetValue(this, label, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the labels in a dictionary and retrieve the one you need via its respective key. This can be viewed as a very simple implementation of the *Strategy Pattern*.

```
var labels = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
labels.Add("TaskSequence", TaskSequenceLabel);
labels.Add("TaskStatus", TaskStatusLabel);
// etc.

attributeValues.ForEach(value => {
    string label = attributes.First(a => a.ID == value.AttributeID).Name;
    labels[value.AttributeName] = label;
});
```

If you need it in multiple places you can refactor it into its own class:

```
public class MyLabels
{
    public Dictionary<string, Label> _labels =
                  new Dictionary<string< Label>();

    public MyLabels() {
        _labels.Add("TaskSequence", TaskSequenceLabel);
        _labels.Add("TaskStatus", TaskStatusLabel);
        // etc.
    }

    public Label Named(string name) {
        return _labels[name];
    }
}

// Usage:
var labels = new MyLabels();
attributeValues.ForEach(value => {
    string label = attributes.First(a => a.ID == value.AttributeID).Name;
    labels.Named(value.AttributeName) = label;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A reflection-only solution will of course do the trick.

I would, however, evaluate the use of a custom attribute with which you could decorate the interested members. Something that you could use to specify the attribute name you're currently switching on.

Looks like a more robust solution to me than to only use reflection, because it's independent of the `TaskSequence` -> `TaskSequenceLabel` convention-based mapping.

With a reflection-only approach, should someone change the name of `TaskSequence`, figuring out why things don't work anymore could be more difficult than it is necessary. If you have an attribute, however, you simply don't care. You *do* care, of course, if the name of the field in the db gets changed.

EDIT

Let me add some code to clarify (pseudo-code actually, I don't have a copy of Visual Studio here).
I will assume it's properties you want to populate.

```
// here's the custom attribute. Ok, should probably be sealed and bla bla bla.

public class MapToAttribute : Attribute {
  readonly string _fieldName;

  public MapToAttribute(string fieldName) {
    _fieldName = fieldName;
  }
}

// here's your model
public class SomeModel {
  [MapTo("TaskSequence")]
  public int TaskSequence { get; set; }
}

// here's how you figure out which property have the MapTo attribute
from p in typeof(SomeModel).GetProperties() where p.IsDefined(typeof(MapToAttribute))
```

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. `PropertyInfo.SetValue` and friends.